# File being uploaded but INSERT is not adding location to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on this for awhile now and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This script seems simple enough and is adding the file to the server but it is not inserting the location to the database. Where have I failed with the INSERT portion of the code?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="photo-upload2.php?district_id=<?php echo $_REQUEST['district_id']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
          Please Enter the Candidate's  Name.
        </p>
        <p>
          Candidate's Name:
        </p>
        <input type="text" name="nameMember"/>
        <p>
            Please Upload a Photo of the Candidate in gif or jpeg format. The file name should be named after the Candidate's name.<br>
            If the same file name is uploaded twice it will be overwritten! Maxium size of File is 35kb. </p>
        <p>
          Photo:
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
        <input type="file" name="photo"> 
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add Pic"/>
      </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php


// This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "../images/candidates/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

// This gets all the other information from the form
$name=$_POST['nameMember'];
$district_id=$_REQUEST['district_num'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


// Connects to your Database
include('db.php');

//Writes the information to the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO candidate_images SET
name='$name',
image='$pic,
district_id='$district_id'";

// Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

// Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}

 else { // if name is blank
    if ($name=='') { echo "Please enter Candidate's name.";

    // Gives and error if it's not ok

    } else echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file $name.";}
?>
```

Comment: You must execute your query ($sql).

Comment: where is your `mysqli` query execution function ??

Comment: is your name is inserting into database? if its inserting then query is correct. try running the query after inserting the image into database and change the name of image using timestamp it will be good otherwise same name of image may get confusing at some level.

Comment: @NerdyDev he is never executing the query. So, no database changes will ever happen. Pathik Vejani gave already an example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert query is wrong, change your query to below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO candidate_images (name,image,district_id) VALUES ('$name','$pic','$district_id')";

mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

See for more reference: [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Here I am providing example, how to insert into database:

```
<?php
    // Database connection establishment
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "MySQL database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO candidate_images (name,image,district_id) VALUES ('$name','$pic','$district_id')";

    // Insert data into database
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>
```

Comment: Yep the trailing apostrophe on $pic was missing, found it by using your suggestion and adding the mysqli_query and adding the     if (!mysql_query($sql))
        echo ('A database error occurred in processing your '.
              'submission.\\nIf this error persists, please '.
              'contact steve@iconmatrix.com.\\n' . mysql_error());

A big thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO candidate_images (`name`,`image`, `district_id`) VALUES ('$name','$pic','$district_id')";
```

Use your `mysql_*` OR `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` functions here for execute query on database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your insert query is wrong. You just need to correct it. It will work fine.
Just replace your code with my following code, do not forget to execute the query saved in $sql variable. This is also necessary. Use your own class / module to execute the query if mine doesn't works

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="photo-upload2.php?district_id=<?php echo $_REQUEST['district_id']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
          Please Enter the Candidate's  Name.
        </p>
        <p>
          Candidate's Name:
        </p>
        <input type="text" name="nameMember"/>
        <p>
            Please Upload a Photo of the Candidate in gif or jpeg format. The file name should be named after the Candidate's name.<br>
            If the same file name is uploaded twice it will be overwritten! Maxium size of File is 35kb. </p>
        <p>
          Photo:
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
        <input type="file" name="photo"> 
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add Pic"/>
      </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php


// This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "../images/candidates/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

// This gets all the other information from the form
$name=$_POST['nameMember'];
$district_id=$_REQUEST['district_num'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


// Connects to your Database
include('db.php');

//Writes the information to the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO `candidate_images` (name,image,district_id) VALUES ('$name','$pic','$district_id')";


// Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

// Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";

mysql_query($sql); // you need to execute the $sql query here to insert the data into database
}

 else { // if name is blank
    if ($name=='') { echo "Please enter Candidate's name.";

    // Gives and error if it's not ok

    } else echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file $name.";}
?>
```